# B&CG is now the definitive place for Magic: the Gathering questions

Tags: discussion, faq, magic-the-gathering

Since many of you likely won't have seen this, I'd like to draw your attention to

[Why is the Magic the Gathering proposal shutting down?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/why-is-the-magic-the-gathering-proposal-shutting-down)

It seems an executive decision has been made that a stand-alone MTG site would not be viable. Board and Card games is now officially *the* place on StackExchange to ask your MTG questions. Which is great, since [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) is the number one most-talked about game on the site, by some margin.

So if you've been holding off on getting stuck in because you were waiting for another site, wait no longer! Tell your friends! More Magic players in this community will lead to better questions, better answers, and more clout when asking the devs for [Magic-specific features](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/668/would-support-for-magic-the-gathering-rendering-make-you-move-site).

Happy questioning. :)

Comment: I think it'd be nice to get some more representation for other collectible games -- L5R and the like -- to go along with our Magic stuff. I just can't contribute much since I don't play any of them. :/

Comment: @Alex P - I agree. On both points. ;)

Comment: Now that we're sorta taking on the proposed site's mantle, I think there is the question of how we feel about the more specific, narrowly-scoped questions -- take note of some of the "top questions" on the proposal, like "What is the best way to counteract <top deck> in <format>?" and "I'm considering [Card A] and [Card B] for my deck. Which would be better?"

Comment: @AlexP - the best way to judge that is just for folks to ask questions as they need the answers.  I assume it is all on topic as long as it meets the usual requirements of the site faq.