# Can we have AutoCard for the site chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Can the existing [AutoCard  feature](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/771/6692) be made available for the [Board and Card Games chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games)?

We discuss cards in that room all the time. Constantly opening new tabs to get links for the cards we are talking about is tedious. Honestly, I think the feature would get *more* use in the chat than it does on the main site.

Comment: +1 As a chat user I think that your claim it would get even more use is actually sound and reasonable. I hadn't considered that before.

Comment: Also, this should probably come with [this trivial bugfix to our autocard feature](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/1153/5573). A previous version [was declined](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/794/5573), but it was declined on the basis that it was just how the search works - well, we were using the incorrect form of search, there's a different URL we should be using and that's all.

Answer (score 7):

You can now use `[mtg:Card Name]` in Chat. I'll have a look at the other AutoCard requests to see if we can bring in some extra improvements.