# Are there other ways to reference Magic cards in posts on BoardgamesExchange?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering

I wanted to write a Magic question here on BoardgamesExchange in which I need to reference some cards. So I wanted to include them in my post, but:

- I don't know if there are more possibilities than just inserting a link to the card from the Magic card database on [wizards.com](https://gatherer.wizards.com)? (e.g. [In Bolas's Clutches](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=442942))

For example as another possibility I could imagine to directly include a picture of the card in the post, but:

- I don't know if it's legal to do so or if I would harm some copyrights there?

Or is there maybe a more syntax based possibility like on [reddit.com/r/magicTCG](https://www.reddit.com/r/magicTCG/comments/b6c559/tagging_cards_in_reddit_post/) by surrounding a card with double brackets (e.g. `[[In Bola's Clutches]]`) which then triggers a bot to post a link to that card as a comment?

It would be nice if there was a possibility which shows the card directly (e.g. as a popup)! So there would be no need to click on that link and open a new page to see the card.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please add support for the Magic AutoCard window](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/please-add-support-for-the-magic-autocard-window)

Answer (score 4):

Boardgames SE has a special shortcut syntax exactly for this: specifically, if you type `[mtg:<card name>]`, for example `[mtg:Black Lotus]`, you will get a link to Gatherer for that card name - e.g. [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d). There are [some issues with this feature](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/switch-magic-autocard-over-to-a-different-search-engine-scryfall) but it works pretty well most of the time.

Note that the link *won't* appear in the preview, but it does appear in the rendered output. (I've also just discovered it's quite hard to stop the rendering happening...)

Comment: I'll just take this opportunity to blatantly self-promote my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script / browser extension that [fixes a bunch of these issues](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1674), including the lack of edit preview.